Trigger Callback After Angular CDK Dialog Closed
I'm using @angular/cdk/dialog to open the component as a modal, not the material component.
I'm trying to know when the modal is closed, the close I mean not showing on the UI anymore. There is an observable closed from DialogRef but it emit new value when the close is triggered not after it close on the UI.
Is there any way I can have callback after dialog close on UI?
